# How do I get into the area Ulukk's Hunger in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am trying to explore every area in Guild Wars 2 right now and one of the areas that I have not been able to get into is [Ulukk's Hunger](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ulukk%27s_Hunger) in [Dredgehaunt Cliffs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dredgehaunt_Cliffs).

Outside the "entrance" to the area, there are two Grawl City Guards and talking to them will yield a reply of "Our city is inside. I am sorry but we do not allow visitors."

How do I get into their city?

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to simply have the area under your belt for the sake of the exploration achievement, I believe you can get this by hugging the edge of the accessible region outside it, similar to the edge-walking you may remember from GW1.

If you want to actually get inside the area, you'll need to choose the Grawl as your [Racial Sympathy](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Racial_sympathy) story choice (asura/charr/norn). This will give you the [Doubt](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Doubt) mission which takes place inside Ulukk's Hunger.

Answer (score 0):

As the wiki says:

> The nearby Grawl City Guard states that this area contains a Grawl city, but it is currently inaccessible. In fact, it s barely possible to reveal this area on the map. From the Grawl City Guards, proceed north into the extremely short tunnel until you reach the ice wall.

I didn't help the Grawl in my personal story, but I have the zone, so hugging the wall is a working method, maybe try to follow the wiki instructions to it, I must admit I got it without noticing.